# How to pass value from BroadcastReceiver to main activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, autostart

I want to tell my MainActivity, that it is starting automatically by BroadcastReceiver when boot is completed. It seems to be possible to send over putExtra some values to the MainActivity like this:

```
public class StartAppAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String key_bootUpStart = "bootUpStart";
private static boolean bootUpStart = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activityIntent.putExtra(key_bootUpStart, bootUpStart);
        context.startActivity(activityIntent);

    }
}
}
```

But how can I receive that value inside my MainActivity?

Comment: `getIntent().getBooleanExtra("bootUpStart", false);`...

Comment: **Please** do not start an activity in this receiver. It will be unreliable, as you have no idea whether this broadcast happens before or after the home screen appears. If you want to take over the foreground when the device boots, **implement your own home screen**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `BroadcastReceiver` you send the intent to the `Activity`.

I modified your key to be public so that you can reuse it.

```
public static final String KEY_BOOTUP_START = "bootUpStart";
```

---

On the `Activity` you process the Intent.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    processExtraData();
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    processExtraData()
}

private void processExtraData()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Use the data here.
    boolean value = getIntent()
        .getBooleanExtra(StartAppAtBootReceiver.KEY_BOOTUP_START, false);
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain why to call `processExtraData();` twice, inside `onCreate(...)` and inside `onNewIntent(...)`?

Comment: Sure thing. `onNewIntent()` is meant as entry point for singleTop activities which already run somewhere else in the stack and therefore won't get `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can get the intent which has started your activiy like:
in `onCreateActivity`:
`Intent intent = getIntent();`

Than:

```
Object value = intent.getExtra("key_bootUpStart");
```